# Routing Questions using Drools

Tags: drools

we need to implement following requirement using Drools engine:
1. Define Questions in each step as a rule.
2. Based on previous question's answer next drop down has to come.

please help how to do this requirement....

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a StatefulKnowledgeSession in drools as your questions are facts that will generate answers as facts.
http://blog.athico.com/2009/03/drools-quick-start-stateful-knowledge.html

This is based on the inference principle.
http://blog.athico.com/2009/11/what-is-inference-and-how-does-it.html

I quote from the link:

> So what is inference? Something is inferred when we gain knowledge of something from using previous knowledge.